# URLConnection does not finish getting InputStream

Tags: android, xamarin, oauth-2.0, httpurlconnection

I create a connection to an authentication server (OAuth 2.0) to get an Token. The method which does this is the following:

```
public static async Task<String> GetToken(string username, string password)
        {
            String response = null;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                URL url = new URL(Configuration.Configuration.baseURL + Configuration.Configuration.tokenPath);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
                urlConnection.DoOutput = true;
                urlConnection.DoInput = true;
                urlConnection.RequestMethod = "POST";
                urlConnection.SetRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "widas_servicebar"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", Configuration.Configuration.scopes)
                });

                //var content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                //content.Add("grant_type", "password");
                //content.Add("username", username);
                //content.Add("password", password);
                //content.Add("client_id", "widas_servicebar");
                //content.Add("scope", Configuration.Configuration.scopes);

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(urlConnection.OutputStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(content);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }

                urlConnection.Connect();
                var stream = urlConnection.InputStream;
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();                    
                    return response;
                }
            });
            return response;
        }
```

Unfortunately when I debug the code it always gets stuck at `var stream = urlConnection.InputStream;` and from there on nothing happens anymore (I tried waiting 15 minutes and using Postman the request gets a response in like 200-500ms).

I used almost the same code for a few other methods which also build a connection to a server (content server) and those work properly.

Is there any error in my code or what could be the reason that the Input stream never finishes?

If it's of any importance: I'm building a Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: There is another similar thread in SO, sorry could not find its url now though, one of the hight voted answer (not accepted one though) says, issue happens only if they put a break point on statement where they are accessing input stream :) In your case var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(urlConnection.OutputStream) So if you are putting break point there remove it and put it on return response; check if response is there or not :) I had same issue did what I said it worked, I know am sounding little crazy worth a try though, lemme know if it worked :) till then lemme find the link :)

Comment: It did not work :/ Would be great if you'd find the link. I will also search the web some more in hopes of finding an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. It seems like what I tried to use didn't work as i thought it would. the now working code looks like this:

```
public static async Task<String> GetToken(string username, string password)
        {
            String response = null;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                URL url = new URL(Configuration.Configuration.baseURL + Configuration.Configuration.tokenPath);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();
                urlConnection.DoOutput = true;
                urlConnection.DoInput = true;
                urlConnection.RequestMethod = "POST";
                urlConnection.SetRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                            

                var content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                content.Add("grant_type", "password");
                content.Add("username", username);
                content.Add("password", password);
                content.Add("client_id", "widas_servicebar");
                content.Add("scope", Configuration.Configuration.scopes);

                Stream os = urlConnection.OutputStream;
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.Write(getQuery(content));
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
                os.Close();

                urlConnection.Connect();
                //var debug = urlConnection.ErrorStream;
                var stream = urlConnection.InputStream;

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();                    
                }
                return response;
            });
            return response;
        }
```

The getQuery method looks like this:

```
private static String getQuery(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            bool first = true;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictionary)
            {      
                if (first)
                {
                    first = false;
                }          
                result.Append(URLEncoder.Encode(entry.Key, "UTF-8"));
                result.Append("=");
                result.Append(URLEncoder.Encode(entry.Value, "UTF-8"));
                result.Append("&");
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you didn't know: There is an Xamarin component called Xamarin.Auth that provides OAuth authentication. You don't have to implement it manually:

Xamnarin.Forms Tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/